# apache mod_rewrite error: incomplete redirection target of [...] for URI [...] modified to [...]

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a php application with the following rewrite rule inside an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ lrs.php [NC,L]
```

The file resides inside an "XAPI" folder of my application. This way, I rewrite requests for `/XAPI/something/ to be handled by the file XAPI/lrs.php`

This has been working just fine on several servers, running various versions of Apache2. However, I have uploaded the application on a different server (Centos6 running apache 2.2.15) and the redirect does not work. In the error logs, I get the message:

incomplete redirection target of `'/XAPI/lrs.php'` for URI `'/path/to/XAPI/lrs.php'` modified to 'http://www.mysite.com/XAPI/lrs.php'

What can be wrong?

Comment: Try changing the target URL to make it a root-anchored path starting from the web server root directory. For example: `RewriteRule .* /XAPI/lrs.php [NC,L]` so that Apache does not have to make assumptions based on a relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug, now fixed...

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=44020

Also look at...
https://enc.com.au/2011/03/04/apache-and-incomplete-redirection-messages/